# ASP.NET DropDownList in ListView's OnItemUpdating method always has a SelectedIndex of 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

In a ListView's `EditTemplate`, I have a DropDownList control. The DropDownList is populated in the `ItemDataBound` method of the `ListView` (only way I found to get the list to populate in the EditTemplate....the DropDownList only exists in the EditTemplate; it must be a label in the `ItemTemplate`).

The list populates, and it all works. The issue I have is when the Update button is clicked and the `ItemUpdating` method is called, the `SelectedIndex` of the DropDownList is *always* zero, no matter which value is selected at the time.

The aspx code, minus the extra templates looks like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" OnItemUpdating="ListView1_ItemUpdating" OnItemEditing="ListView1_ItemEditing">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
    <td><asp:DropDownList CssClass="vaultDropDownList" ID="EditStaffList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="True"></asp:DropDownList></td>
    <td>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
       <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And the codebehind:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{            
    ListView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}

protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.DisplayIndex == ListView1.EditIndex)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = e.Item.FindControl("EditStaffList") as DropDownList;
        BindDropDownList(ddl);
    }
}

protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList staff = ListView1.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("EditStaffList") as DropDownList;

   //SQL update stuff will go here
   ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
}
```

If I try to populate the DropDownList in the `Page_Load` method to use `IsPostBack`, the dropdown control always returns `null`.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Edit: The ListView bind:

```
protected void DisplayListView(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string connString = SQLstringTooLong; 
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString); 
    DataTable initialTable = new DataTable(); 
    string queryStatement = "SELECT lotsastuff"; 
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryStatement, sqlConnection); 
    dataAdapter.Fill(initialTable); 
    ListView1.DataSource = initialTable; 
    ListView1.DataBind(); 
}
```

Edit2: Here's the dropdownlist bind method:

```
public static void CreateStaffList(DropDownList list, string searchGroup) 
{ 
    ArrayList userList = new ArrayList(); 
    //more SQL stuff 
    list.DataSource = userList; 
    list.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: Can we please see how you are binding the data to your ListView? I suspect you are binding it on every PostBack.

Comment: I'm binding it in the ItemDataBound method, as above. I suspect I am, too, but don't know how to bind it only in the EditTemplate and not in the ItemTemplate anywhere but the ItemDataBound method for the ListView.

Comment: The `ItemDataBound` event is actually only part of the data binding process. What I'm looking for is when you actually set a DataSource and call DataBind. The code would look something like `ListView1.DataSource = someDataSource;` and `ListView1.DataBind();`. My guess is these lines are in your `Page_Load` event. Could I please see how you are doing this DataBinding?

Comment: You bet! The binding is here:

Comment: Ok and where do you call the `DisplayListView` method?

Comment: In Page_Load, initially.

Comment: Ok and are you making sure not to call `DisplayListView` on every PostBack? In other words, is your `DisplayListView` called wrapped in an `if (!IsPostBack)`?

Comment: Oy, that was it! I wrapped that call in an if (!IsPostback) brace in Page_Load and the problem is solved. I had forgotten that the initial page load isn't a post back. Thank you very much for your help; that was a frustrating problem.

Comment: Great! You're welcome. I know that one has bit me in the past too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you aren't binding your ListView on every PostBack. Wrap it in a condition to check for that.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DisplayListView();
    }
}
```

If you don't, your entire ListView, including your DropDownLists will rebind. This would cause you DropDownList to reset its SelectedIndex to 0.

Comment: Can't upvote as yet, but wanted to say thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem! Welcome to StackOverflow!